# Counts on single column for different conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I require 3 different counts on single column for different conditions.

Table structure:

```
interview-
id-int(10)
c_id-int(10)
experience-varchar2(100)
```

experience have 3 different values-
1)positive
2)negative
3)neutral

I require 3 different counts of "count_positive", "count_negative" and "count_neutral" for where condition of c_id=10.

I know it can get by 3 different queries. Can I able to get 3 counts by single query?

Comment: Can I get active record query for codeigniter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE experience
          WHEN 'positive' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END) AS CountPositive
   , SUM(CASE experience
            WHEN 'negative' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS CountNegative
   , SUM(CASE experience
            WHEN 'neutral' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS CountNeutral
FROM Interview
WHERE c_id = 10
```

Comment: Weneger: The last ELSE condition is empty, 0 should be placed there i guess.

Comment: @yaqubAhmad Good catch, thank you. I added the 0 to the last `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'Positive Count' , count(*)
from interview
where experience = 'positive'
UNION
select 'Negative Count' , count(*)
from interview
where experience = 'negative'
UNION
select 'Neutral' , count(*)
from interview
where experience = 'neutral'
```

Comment: Have you seen this statement "I know it can get by 3 different queries" in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the modified version of Adam Wenger answer:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE experience
          WHEN 'positive' THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
       END) AS CountPositive
   , COUNT(CASE experience
            WHEN 'negative' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
         END) AS CountNegative
   , COUNT(CASE experience
            WHEN 'neutral' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
         END) AS CountNeutral
FROM Interview
WHERE c_id = 10
```

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I got solution. You can check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works fine:

```
select 'count of ' + experience, 
       count(experience) 
from interview 
where c_id=10
group by experience
```

Comment: `+` is not a concatenation operator in MySQL. `||` is, but in ANSI SQL mode only.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for active record query in Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('SUM(CASE experience
          WHEN "positive" THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END) AS CountPositive
   , SUM(CASE experience
            WHEN "negative" THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS CountNegative
   , SUM(CASE experience
            WHEN "neutral" THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS CountNeutral');

$this->db->where('c_id',10);
$query=$this->db->get('interview');
$result=$query->result();

$interview_experience=$result[0];
$positive_count=$interview_experience->CountPositive;
$negative_count=$interview_experience->CountNegative;
$neutral_count=$interview_experience->CountNeutral;
```